# HTML is not dynamically adding value attributes for form fields in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Contact Me form which is displayed in the modal. When the inputs are incorrect, the user is directed to a dedicated Contact Me page.

**Form in modal :**

[image]

**Dedicated page for the form :**

[image]

I am trying to show input errors straightaway in the modal itself. I am using `on-blur` function to do this. The issue is that, the form field values aren't dynamically updated for forms in the modal. The form field values are however updated in the dedicated page.

**HTML for forms in modal (value attribute not appearing) :**

[image]

**HTML for forms in dedicated page (value attribute correctly shown):**

[image]

And also, jQuery doesn't detect the form fields in modal but detects the fields in the dedicated page.

**jQuery code :**

```
$(document).on('blur', '#id_name', function() {
    var name = $(this).val();
    alert(name);  // works only in the dedicated page !
});
```

Any help? Thanks !

Comment: when do you call your jQuery snippet in order to manipulate the modal, is the modal already displayed?

Comment: I have it in the end of the script. I am using Django, and it appears in the `base.html` after `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`. So, the modal is displayed already before the jQuery.

Comment: if you `console.log($('#id_name'));` do you see the element in the console or do you get `undefined`?

Comment: It shows nothing during page load. On modal form submit button, the log is made. it says `[<input id="id_name">] (1)` but on clicking it shows nothing. However, on dedicated page, it shows the exact input tag.

Comment: sure because on dedicated page the html is already there, when you trigger your script in case of the modal, the element is not there, so your issue. Could you show me how do you load the modal please?

Comment: Here is my entire code : https://pastebin.com/ct0hhQgj.

Comment: in which line is your modal opened? I can see only all the onblur settings here

Comment: I have made a comment on line 27. I am loading the modal there.

Comment: wrap all your script which starts from line 40, inside this:
`$(document).ready(function() {//put all your code here});` and let me know if this fixes your issue

Comment: I kinda got it working. I made a mistake. You were right. The jQuery still loads first before the modal because I have included `{% extends "personal/base.html" %}` in the top of the original page. I just moved the script to a seperate file and included it in the end of the page. It works now. But i have to fix a lot of other issues which were caused because of the move. Thanks ! Want to make it as an answer ?

Comment: Yeah thanks, so it can be also useful for other people. If you have other issues related to this, please reply to the below answer. Btw maybe wrapping all your code inside what I said will fix your issues because you still have everything in the same page, but I strongly recommend you to move all in a separate js file. It's a bad practice to mix js and styles inside the HTML :)

Comment: Yeah totally agree on that. I will move to a seperate file.

Comment: Another little suggestion. When you assign styles through JS, think instead to add/remove CSS classes, and keep your styles always inside CSS files. It makes clearer the separation :)

Comment: Haha yes. I do keep all styles separately. In this case, I have styles in AWS. So I had to upload it. I could however get the style from my local machine.  But for quick testing purpose, I just added them to the HTML tag. I will move them surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your script, your modal isn't attached to the page yet so the elements can't be retrieved. Wrap all your script inside this:

`$(document).ready(function() { //here all my code });`

And you should fix the issue